# where is toolbox and server explorer windows in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed microsoft visual studio 2013 .unfortunately i closed server explorer and toolbox windows in the left side of panel.how can I return them?please help me.

Comment: Use the Quick Launch search box on the top right

Comment: On tasks bar go to "View" and select Solution Explorer" and Toolbox".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see a window or a tool pane, you can **usually** find it on the <kbd>View</kbd> menu. If you don't see it there, be sure to check the cascading <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> option. Some windows related to debugging are on the <kbd>Debug</kbd> menu under <kbd>Windows</kbd>.

The cool thing is that you don't actually need to learn this. Just go to the Quick Launch (at the top right) and start typing what you're looking for:

[image]

You can click the option you want from the dropdown menu and it will be executed for you. Optionally, you can learn the menu command or the keyboard shortcut for next time, but if you don't do it very often, you can use always use Quick Launch.